# swfupload selecting directory for upload

Tags: flash, swfupload

is there a way to allow the user to select a Directory/Folder on there computer and have all the *.doc files upload?

Comment: why not just have swfupload limit the files to doc and have them go into the folder and press ctrl + a?

Comment: will CTRL+A work on mac? the user of the upload script are not computer savvy. Just trying to find the easiest way for them to upload all *.doc files. I know on the PC you have to select at least 1 file before pressing CTRL+A, so i'm pretty sure someone would try and press CTRL+A before selecting a file.

Comment: ok I wouldn't have given that comment if you added that you are using mac. good luck. btw you do not need select a file before doing a ctrl+a. just a noob pc user tip

Comment: It's Command-A on the Mac.  Other than that - same thing.

Comment: @mezzie - That also fails if all *.doc files _recursively_ are desired. Select-All won't dig into sub-directories.